# Using RDP to shadow your own session - W10 enterprise

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

Users have access to two computers, one is in their office, on the corporate network, with access to the internet, intranet and so on.

The other is on the shopfloor, on an industrial network with basically no access to the outside world.

When in the shopfloor, they sometimes need to have a glance into their office computer (ie. check the internet for spelling, a data sheet, or whatever).

Instead of giving the industrial network access to the proxy, which is a whole can of worms, I have allowed RDP from the industrial network to the corporate, and users can RDP into their office computer, and do whatever they need to do.

However, if their session is opened on their office computer, they cannot connect, and have to go back to the office to close the session, which defeats the entire point.

Both machines running W10 Enterprise, is there a way to set things up, so that RDP works, basically, like VNC, and gives them interactive access to the already opened session, without having to do anything on the office computer?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a 100% sure if this is still valid (contrary information on the Internet).
It seems work fine in my case (W10 Pro PC and remote connection from a Mac using the Microsoft RDP client for MacOS), but the user-account I use is an Administrator on the W10 machine. That may make a difference.

Connect to the remote machine using the RDP client started with the additional command-line parameter "/admin". (You can edit the shortcut for the RDP client to always include the parameter.) On really old RDP clients the parameter is /console instead of /admin.
PLEASE NOTE: This DOESN'T grant admin-rights to the user!

This causes the RDP client to connect to the local session on the remote computer (AKA the session a locally logged on user is using) and take that over. (If no one is locally logged on it simple starts that sessions as if someone was logging in locally at the machine.)
If the user-account used for local logins and remote logins is the same user you will simply be taking over the existing session, including open applications, etc.

If someone else (different user) is logged in locally or remotely as well that person will get a popup message that another logon attempt is being made. The already logged in user can block the login attempt. There is no way to prevent that as far as I know.

Of course the user should NOT log out (remotely or locally) as that will terminate the session and give you a fresh session on the next connect.
Locally just lock the computer (or have the screensaver/powermanagement do that automatically). From the RDP session simply disconnect in stead of logout (most users are prone to doing that by simply closing the RDP window anyway).